# How can I change the language of Spring exceptions

Tags: java, exception, internationalization

I am working with a server in spanish and my Spring logged exceptions are translated to Spanish. That is a nice feature but I will prefer to have them in English because it makes easier to find answers in google (and Stackoverflow)

How can I change thouse messages? In my Log4J config file? in the context file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it via jvm args.

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using

Comment: Thanks, it worked. And I can set the parameters in eclipse for just some testing configurations for Junit. Great!